# C# xml read all childnodes

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm completely new to C# and XML parsing so I like to ask how can I read all nodes within this xml file?

```
<root>
    <info>
        <name>
            <first>bob</first>
            <last>john</last>
            <middle>D</middle>
        </name>
        <age>35</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <id>12345</id>
    </info>

    <info>
        <name>
            <first>jack</first>
            <last>dawnson</last>
            <middle>D</middle>
        </name>
        <age>23</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <id>23456</id>
    </info>
</root>
```

I could get the value for age,sex,and id but not name or its childnodes.Here is what I got so far?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.LoadXml(xmlOut);  
XmlNodeList node = doc.SelectNodes("/root/Info");  
Employee empOne = new Employee();  

foreach (XmlNode childNode in node)  
{
    empOne.Age = childNode["age"].InnerText;
    empOne.Sex = childNode["sex"].InnerText;
    empOne.ID = childNode["id"].InnerText;

    foreach (XmlNode node2 in childNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        empOne.FirstName = node2["first"].InnerText;
        empOne.LastName = node2["last"].InnerText;
    }  
}
```

Comment: First, I'd *strongly* recommend using LINQ to XML - it'll make everything a lot simpler.

Comment: I think you need a recursive search - //?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foreach (XmlNode node2 in childNode["name"].ChildNodes)`?

Comment: @Dialecticus: This doesn't work! It gave me a NullReferenceException. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small example-application with your xml using Linq to XML. To parse your XML you can use the following method:

```
internal List<Employee> ReadEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    string fileName = "XMLFile1.xml";
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        if (document.Root != null)
        {
            foreach (XElement infoElement in document.Root.Elements("info"))
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();

                XElement ageElement = infoElement.Element("age");
                XElement sexElement = infoElement.Element("sex");
                XElement idElement = infoElement.Element("id");
                XElement nameElement = infoElement.Element("name");

                if (ageElement != null)
                    employee.Age = ageElement.Value;
                if (sexElement != null)
                    employee.Sex = sexElement.Value;
                if (idElement != null)
                    employee.Id = idElement.Value;

                if (nameElement != null)
                {
                    var firstnameElement = nameElement.Element("first");
                    var lastnameElement = nameElement.Element("last");
                    if (firstnameElement != null)
                        employee.Firstname = firstnameElement.Value;
                    if (lastnameElement != null)
                        employee.Lastname = lastnameElement.Value;
                }
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
    }
    return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by making class and then convert it to xml..

```
 public class Root
 {
    public List<Info> infos{ get; set; }
    public Root()
    {

    }
    public Root(List<Info> infos)
    {
        this.infos = new List<Info>();
        this.infos = infos;
    }
  }


 public class Info
 {
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public String sex { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
 }


 public class Name 
{
    public String first { get; set; }
    public String last { get; set; }
    public String middle { get; set; }
}



  class XmlConvertor
{
    public String GetXmlFromObject<T>(T obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        nameSpace.Add("", "");
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        StringWriter sr = new StringWriter();

        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sr, settings);
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, nameSpace);
         return sr.ToString();
    }
    public T GetObjectFromXml<T>(String xmlString)
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
            .Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));

    }

}
```

and in your main class you can use this method..

```
  Root root = new XmlConvertor().GetObjectFromXml<Root>("your xml in string");
```

then you can use this root variable and can get every value you want..
i know it is little bit lengthy but it is more flexible because you dont have to hard code name of nodes

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would've used some simple LINQ2XML to query it

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml);

var p = xdoc.Root.Elements("info").Select(x => new { first = x.Element("name").Element("first").Value,
    last = x.Element("name").Element("last").Value,
    middle = x.Element("name").Element("middle").Value,
    age = x.Element("age").Value, 
    sex = x.Element("sex").Value, id = x.Element("id").Value});
```

you'll have to build a new object for it if you need to pass it on though.